# cast UITextView to UITextField

Tags: ios5, casting, uitextfield, uitextview

This may seem like a very simple question, however I haven't been able to discover a simple option yet...

I have a series of UITextFields followed by a UITextView.  How can I incorporated the TextFields and the TextView in the same method below.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField{
textField = activeField;
if([self.textField1 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textField1;}
else if([self.textField2 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textField2;}
else if([self.textField3 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textField3;}
else if([self.textView1 isFirstResponder]){ activeField = textView1;}

[scrollView1 scrollRectToVisible:[activeField frame] animated:YES];

return NO;
}
```

The last line causes a warning of:

**Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UITextField *_*strong' from 'UITextView **_strong'**

This is due (I'm sure) to the obvious fact that the UITextField and the UITextView are different Objects... which is fine however is there a way to get around this as I wish to be able to advance through the textFields and TextViews with a next and previous button.

as per this method

```
-(void) nextTextField:(id)sender{
if([self.textField1 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textField2;}
else if([self.textField2 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textField3;}
else if([self.textField3 isFirstResponder]){activeField = textView1;}
else if([self.textView1 isFirstResponder]){ activeField = textField1;}
}
```

I was hoping for a casting sort of option however I am a little confused as to how to cast in objective C...  This might sound dumb however

```
activeField = ((UITextField) textView1);
```

is how I'd have cast in Java but it seems I just can't seem to get he syntax right.
Should I cast to a UIView as they both inherit from that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you don't need to store activeField, for this method, so the only relevant code would be your nextTextField: method.  Try changing it to:

```
-(void) nextTextField:(id)sender{
          if([self.textField1 isFirstResponder]) {[textField2 becomeFirstResponder];}
     else if([self.textField2 isFirstResponder]) {[textField3 becomeFirstResponder];}
     else if([self.textField3 isFirstResponder]) {[textView1  becomeFirstResponder];}
     else if([self.textView1 isFirstResponder])  {[textField1 becomeFirstResponder];}
}
```

You don't need to cast to a different type or anything.

Comment: Cheers... that was helpful.  The become first responder works well, however the scrollToRect on the textField(s)/view(s) is now complaining. I have ticked you answer as it did address question and your suggestion worked.

Comment: Thanks, now that you have 10 points you can "up-vote" answers that you find helpful as well, by clicking the up arrow above he check mark.  You can do this for **all** answers that are helpful, and not just the one where you tick the correct answer.  This will give the people helping you points for answering your question!  As far as your scrolling issue, if you haven't worked it out, feel free to post another question and I'm sure that we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few issues with your thinking.  You will need to go down two levels to get to a common super type.  Both UITextField and UITextView are "visible" components so they inherit from UIView.  They can both be cast to UIView but not to each other.  But this won't help you with your question. I think you may be struggling with delegation also.

The method textFieldDidBeginEditing: is a delegate call and it only works with UITextField.  This is why the class that contains your method above should implement UITextFieldDelegate.  When you set focus to the UITextField, UITextField first checks to see that the delegate is not nil.  If the delegate property holds a class then UITextField checks to see if it implements the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method explicitly.  If the method is implemented in the delegate then the UITextField calls the method.

It is no different with the UITextView.  However UITextView doesn't even know about the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method.  It has its own delegate and its own method that performs the same general function as textFieldDidBeginEditing:.  The UITextView version of this method is called textViewDidBeginEditing:.  Like the UITextfield the UITextView checks that the delegate is not nil and that it implements textViewDidBeginEditing:.  If these requirements are met then UITextView will textViewDidBeginEditing.  However UITextView will never call textFieldDidBeginEditing:.

Finally objects cannot be cast into something they're not.  They can only be cast as its own type or any of its ancestors.

You will need to set up both each components' method (textFieldDidBeginEditing and textViewDidBeginEditing) for this to work.

Hope this helps.